# How to add foreign key in migration where reference table has no id column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to add a new table to my Rails project with several references to other tables. However, the foreign tables don't have `:id` columns; I set them up to each have a string `:code` column instead as their primary keys.

Here's an example of one table that I'll be referencing:

```rb
class CreateReasons < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def up
    create_table :reasons, id: false do |t|
      t.string :code
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end
    execute "ALTER TABLE reasons ADD PRIMARY KEY (code);"
  end

  def down
    drop_table :reasons
  end
end
```

The resulting Postgres description is exactly what I want:

```
development-# \d reasons
                           Table "public.reasons"
   Column    |            Type             | Collation | Nullable | Default 
-------------+-----------------------------+-----------+----------+---------
 code        | character varying           |           | not null | 
 description | character varying           |           |          | 
 created_at  | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
 updated_at  | timestamp without time zone |           | not null | 
Indexes:
    "reasons_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (code)
```

What I want is for my new table, let's call it `TestModel` to have a column called `:reason_code` that is a foreign key reference to the primary key of the `reasons` table.

Things I've tried:

1. `add_reference :test_models, :reasons, column: :code, type: :string, name: :reason_code, foreign_key: true` below the table creation. Error is `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist`
2. `add_foreign_key :test_models, :reasons, column: :code, type: :string, name: :reason_code` below the table creation. Error is `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "code" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist`
3. Inside the table creation: 
   `t.references :reason_code, foreign_key: { to_table: :reasons }` and 
   `t.references :reason_code, foreign_key: { to_table: :reasons, column: :code }` 
   both give me the error `PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "id" referenced in foreign key constraint does not exist`

And several other permutations of these functions. Is there a way to do this within Rails, preferably without executing more raw SQL?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why would you omit the id column? It seems like begging for trouble (like you're experiencing now).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to use `primary_key` option in your foreign key migration, it defaults to column `id` and that is the reason, why you are getting an error:

```
add_foreign_key :test_models, :reasons, column: :reason_code, primary_key: :code
```

See the documentation for `add_foreign_key` method, there is a more info about it https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/SchemaStatements.html#method-i-add_foreign_key

Comment: Thank you so much! 

For anyone else trying to do the same thing, the complete solution required two parts:

1. adding the column as a string in the `create_table` command: `t.string :reason_code`

2. adding the line from @edariedl below the table creation.

Comment: best. We still need to specify has and belongs_to attributes on both the models, right?

Comment: Of course, if you want to access related records from those models. You just have to properly set `foreign_key` and `primary_key` in `has_many` and `belongs_to` definitions to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

[This person](http://ruby-journal.com/how-to-override-default-primary-key-id-in-rails/) indicates your migration should look like:

```
class CreateReasons < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products, id: false do |t|
      t.string :code, null: false
      t.string :description

      t.timestamps
    end

    add_index :products, :code, unique: true
  end
end
```

and that your model should look like:

```
class Reason < ApplicationRecord
  self.primary_key = 'code'
end
```